# LLVM - why @a is type of i32*

Tags: llvm

I don't understand why `@a` is type of `i32*`. Can someone explain it me, please?

```
@a = internal global i32 0
define i32 @main() {
  store i32 42, i32* @a
  %1 = load i32* @a
  ret i32 %1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the language reference](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#global-variables) (emphasis mine):

> Global variables define **regions of memory** allocated at compilation time instead of run-time.
>   [...]
>   As SSA values, global variables define pointer values that are in scope (i.e. they dominate) all basic blocks in the program. **Global variables always define a pointer to their “content” type** because they describe a region of memory, and all memory objects in LLVM are accessed through pointers.